# Is it OK to copy answers to the same question?

Tags: discussion

I only raise this question now as similar just happened to me, but I've witnessed this behaviour several times:

1. Somebody asks a question
2. Person A answers
3. Person B provides the same answer and links some time later
4. Sometimes Person B receives upvotes from friends/etc. as soon as they answer
5. Person C answers adding something constructive
6. Person B Again copies the new information into their own answer

Sometimes Person B answers first but with no information or something far far wide of the mark, and then waits until somebody posts the correct answer to update their own. I've seen this happen before where Person B has had an outright wrong answer then 20 mins after person A answers, they delete their original answer and post Person A's answer again.

This doesn't seem like behaviour that should be tolerated, is it? Is there some way to flag this? (I'm asking in general, not because I plan to flag the newbie who just did this to me)

Comment: I swear to you I did a search >.< /fail

Comment: Let me copy an answer from that dup and post as an answer before this question gets closed, just for the rep :-)