# I just posted on a closed question on the iOS app

Tags: bug, answers, closed-questions, ios-app

I just posted on a closed question
[Is it OK to copy answers to the same question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222773//222777#222777)

How?

Side point:

I do not see any indication that the post is closed on the app

Comment: The app currently does not support closed question and as you can see they are not listed anywhere... and as the dupe says there is a long "grace period" to post answers after question is closed.

Comment: The question showed up in my questions list
 @shadow so the fix to not show closed questions must not be workin

Comment: No closed questions for me... but on the other hand no feed for me too, so maybe it's all user-specific. Maybe you were viewing old list and didn't refresh?

Comment: Yeah, it's not *impossible* to stumble on a closed question in the app right now, but you typically won't...this will all be addressed once the app actually supports closed questions anyway.

Comment: I have stumbled onto closed questions **many** times on the app @TimStone